# Remove white space caused by using border radius

Tags: css

I have two div elements separated by "border-top-left-radius: 500px 20px;" and "border-top-right-radius: 500px 20px;". My problem is to fill the white space caused by that radius with the color of previous div element. [Here is a picture of my problem.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XUF5N.jpg) As you can see, there is white space in corners between two divs i need to fill with grey color from the upper div.

```
.upper {
    background-color: grey;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.downer {
    border-top-left-radius: 500px 20px;
    border-top-right-radius: 500px 20px;
    border-bottom: none;
    border-left: none;
    border-right: none;
}
```

Comment: code code code code code...

Comment: Can you post your html and css code

Comment: I edited my question with code updates. I hope you can help me now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by adding overlap method `position: relative;` and `bottom: 18px;` to second div. So the css code of second div looks like this

```
.downer {
   position: relative;
   bottom: 18px;
   border-top-left-radius: 500px 20px;
   border-top-right-radius: 500px 20px;
   border-bottom: none;
   border-left: none;
   border-right: none;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

**working fine for my case **
radius take some space so we need more width so that why set with 101%**

```
.upper {
    
    with: 50px; /// set according to your requirement
}
.downer {
 position: relative;
    width:101% !important;
    max-width: 101% !important;
    flex: 0 0 101% !important;
    margin: -0.1rem;
  
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to set background-color to grey for the parent of upper and downer and background-color to white for downer

Comment: For example when I add third div and I want all three divs to be colored differently, I can't do it with your suggestion.

Comment: You can, set the background-color to the color you want for the third div and you are done

Comment: White space around div borders is not some deafult color, it is the background-color of the parent div